# Split check-boxes that was populated with ng-repeat into columns?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

Here is my html:

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectedAll.value" ng-click="checkAll()" />Check All
    </label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox" ng-repeat="carType in carTypeObj">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="carType.selected" /> {{carType.type}}
    </label>
</div>
```

Here is my controller:

```
carApp.controller("TableBodyCtrl", function($scope, $http){
    $scope.selectedAll = {"value":true};
    $scope.carTypeObj = [{"type":"hatchback"},{"type":"suv"}...];
```

Here is my output in chrome:

[image]

And here is the output I need:

[image]

Because I am populating my check-boxes using AngularJS ng-repeat, this should be achieved using AngularJS.

So what is an appropriate way to achieve it?

Note: I am using bootstrap 3.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can do this with pure css:

Add to your css file:

```
div.checkbox > label{
    display:inline-block;
    width:150px;
}
```

And for your html

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectedAll.value" ng-click="checkAll()" />Check All
    </label>
    <label ng-repeat="carType in carTypeObj">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="carType.selected" /> {{carType.type}}
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Note you can also use relative width if you want a fixed number of column. Use width:20% instead of width:150px

Comment: can you give me fiddle or plunker?

Comment: Ok, you also need to change a little bit your html. Check this: http://plnkr.co/edit/pqOTStRlzmclGJ0TTVYA

Answer (score 0):

> Use BootStrap's **checkbox-inline** class like below.

```
<label class="checkbox-inline" ng-repeat="carType in carTypeObj"> 
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="carType.selected" /> {{carType.type}}
    </label>
```

> Now based on the screen width, checkbox will adjust accordingly.

Here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/py6rdhy7/).

Thanks.